# onEditorAction in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two EditTexts and a Button in my layout

an EditText called UserName and another called Password and the Button is called Login

the Button is disabled at the start

what I want is that when ever anything is inputted in EditText UserName and Password the Button should be Enabled

here is what i tried

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(UserName.getText()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(PassWord.getText()))
    {
        Login.setEnabled(true);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
```

when I run this code the Login Button start as disabled 
and it stays disabled when I input something in both the EditTexts
without clicking the Enter Button

it Only works when I click the Enter Button

is there a way to make it work when any button in the keypad is clicked and both of the EditTexts not empty

Thanks for help

Comment: What you need is a text watcher on both edit texts, because onEditorAction is something else (enter, next, done - special buttons on keyboard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TextChangedListener` class for `EditTexts` to listen for events, when the text changes in them. I have a code for this in one of my projects:

```
private boolean heightFilled;
private boolean weightFilled;

private void setInputListeners() {
    etHeight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            heightFilled = s.length() > 0;
            calculateButton.setEnabled(heightFilled && weightFilled);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    etWeight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            weightFilled = s.length() > 0;
            calculateButton.setEnabled(heightFilled && weightFilled);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}
```

This should work, if you change the names of the `Button` and the `EditText`s.

Comment: Worked! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a textchanged listener. From in there you can check as typing if both have an input and call code for activating your button there after checks.

```
   editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             //enter code here to check if your edittexts have content
             //then do stuff with your button

            }

        }
    });
```